Cross context web application tomcat with Spring Web MVC, ClassCastException
I am exploring few things in tomcat with Cross Context setup as described here. Both my applications are Spring web mvc based web apps, below are version details.
<java.version>21</java.version>
<spring.version>6.1.9</spring.version>
<hibernate.version>6.2.4.Final</hibernate.version>

apache-tomcat-10.1.24

However while accessing another application's context in a @Controller @GetMapping, I am getting below error.
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.http.server.DefaultRequestPath cannot be cast to class org.springframework.http.server.RequestPath (org.springframework.http.server.DefaultRequestPath is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @4816278d; org.springframework.http.server.RequestPath is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @287bdaf3)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    com.nividous.cc.controller.PersonController.includeContent(PersonController.java:48)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926)

I am using below code to access the context of another application.
// Get the ServletContext of the other web application
        ServletContext otherContext = request.getServletContext().getContext("/slave");

        if (otherContext != null) {
            String targetUrl = null;
            targetUrl = "/slave" + request.getPathInfo();
            // Get the RequestDispatcher for the target resource
            RequestDispatcher rd = otherContext.getRequestDispatcher(targetUrl);

            if (rd != null) {
                // Include the content of the target resource in the response
                rd.include(request, response);
            }
        }

Update
This looks like more of a spring issue, something similar which spring does have known conflicts with cross context applications.. The post is too old but I can see from the error points to similar directions.
Update 2
It's not specifically spring issue but classloader issue, it's just that spring uses some properties added to the request as attributes which are not being retrieved due to different classloader in place of two different web applications.
Update 3
Need to try this out.
